# How do I protect Raspberry Pi Webcam over internet

Tags: networking, webcam, security

I have already worked out how to use the Pi with a webcam and have even managed to link it to a port on the router and access from an external pc it over the internet.  But I am very aware that it was probably insecure and open to anyone on the net.  I want to ensure that only those who I grant access to can access the video stream over the internet.  How do I do that?  Are the changes I need to make on the Pi or in the router and if either what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you give some more info on your setup, you may get better answers. Which OS do you use? Which program for streaming video. Are you behind a proxy? etc...

Answer (score 1):

In your router you could set source IP addresses in the firewall to only let certain addresses connect but that would not help if people are not always on the same address.

On the pi use SSL based authentication in the web server. There is a good introduction here: http://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is setup an [OpenVPN](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN) connection.

Comment: Instead of posting a link-only answer, it would be better to post the essential parts of the link here to avoid link rot and so people don't have to go site-hopping to find an answer.